# django: Why is RequestContext set as context_instance?

Tags: django, django-templates

It seems most documentation recommends :

```
template_values = {}
template_values["foo"] = "bar"
return render_to_response(path, template_values, context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

Why don't I use :

```
template_values = RequestContext(request)
template_values["foo"] = "bar"
return render_to_response(path, template_values)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RequestContext` doesn't inherit from `dict`, and as such is not guaranteed to implement all of `dict`'s methods (and it doesn't), and any functions that operate on dicts may not work, either. Lastly, there's no reason to; it's better to consider it an opaque object whose implementation may change. Using a `dict` to provide the template's context has all the benefits and none of the drawbacks of `RequestContext`.

### Update

To produce less boilerplate code, here are two utility functions I use. I put them in a shortcuts.py file at the base of my project.

```
from django.template import RequestContext
def render_template(request, template, data=None):
    "Wrapper around render_to_response that fills in context_instance for you."
    response = render_to_response(template, data,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return response

def boilerplate_render(template):
    "Factory function for creating simple views that only forward to a template"
    def view(request, **kwargs):
        response = render_template(request, template, kwargs)
        return response
    return view
```

Usage:

```
def my_view(request):
    # Do stuff here...
    return render_template(request, 'my_template.html', {'var1': 'value', etc..})

my_view2 = boilerplate_render('my_template2.html') # Takes no context parameters
```

Comment: wonderful. thank you. my last line seems kind of verbose, and appears at the end of every one of my views. any recommendations so that I don't keep copying and pasting this?

Answer (score 4):

In regards to "boiler-plate code", this is already built in to Django. Just use the generic view:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

def my_view(request):
    # Do stuff here...
    return direct_to_template(request, 'my_template.html', {'var1': 'value', etc..})
```

Answer (score 2):

Been banging my head on Django boilerplate for a while now. Django has (at least) three very similar functions for template rendering, each with a varying degree of shortcutedness:

```
django.shortcuts.render_to_response
django.template.loader.render_to_string
django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template
```

It seems that at least two of these (probably render_to_response and direct_to_template) could be refactored into a single, less boilerplatish, shortcut.

`django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template` is almost good enough on its own, but unfortunately puts keyword arguments in a `params` dict, making it incompatible with most uses of `render_to_response` (template refactoring is often necessary when switching from `render_to_response` to `direct_to_template`). `render_to_response`, which ironically lives in django.shortcuts, is hardly a well-thought-out shortcut. It should convert keyword arguments to template parameters and that ungainly `context_instance` argument is just too long to type ... often.

I've attempted a more useful shortcut. Note the use of `*request_and_template_and_params` to prevent clashes between template parameter names and positional argument names.

```
def render(*request_and_template_and_params, **kwargs):
    """Shortcut for rendering a template with RequestContext

    Takes two or three positional arguments: request, template_name, and
    optionally a mapping of template parameters. All keyword arguments,
    with the excepiton of 'mimetype' are added to the request context.

    Returns a HttpResponse object.
    """
    if len(request_and_template_and_params) == 2:
        request, template_name = request_and_template_and_params
        params = kwargs
    else:
        request, template_name, params = request_and_template_and_params
        params = dict(params) # copy because we mutate it
        params.update(kwargs)
    httpresponse_kwargs = {'mimetype': params.pop('mimetype', None)}
    context = RequestContext(request, params)
    return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(
        template_name, context_instance=context), **httpresponse_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found this solution [here](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2008/may/10/getting-requestcontext-your-templates/) and i modificate it just a litle:

```
def render_to(template_name):
    def renderer(func):
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kw):
            output = func(request, *args, **kw)
            if not isinstance(output, dict):
                return output
            return render_to_response(template_name, output,
                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        return wrapper
    return renderer

@render_to('my_template.html')
def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    return some_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to the "boiler plate" code, you could render to a template in your urls.py

For example:

```
url(r'^about/$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'about.html',}),
```